# Handle relational database with Webflux in an no sql model

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm trying to handle a relational database without having native sql queries inside the code. And I was thinking about this solution for getting all categories objects considering that a Category has a property of type Multimedia.

```
public Flux<Category> getAllCategories() {

    return categoriesRepository.findAll().map(categoryDao -> {
                if (categoryDao.getMediaId() != null) {
                    return multimediaRepository.findById(categoryDao.getMediaId())
                            .map( multimediaDao -> categoryMapper.daoToDomainWithMultimedia(categoryDao, multimediaDao));
                }
                return categoryMapper.daoToDomain(categoryDao);
            });
}
```

and this is the error that I'm having inside the IDE:

no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono conforms to Category inference variable V has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Category lower bounds

I'm new to this reactive programming and any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: first of all if `categoriesRepository.findAll()` is a reactive repository, it will never return null, since null is not allowed in reactive flows. If not found it will return a `Mono#empty` and should be handled in a `switchIfEmpty` operator after the first `map` statement. Second, you have not disclosed the return types of `daoToDomainWithMultimedia` and `daoToDomain`. remember that in your declaration you have stated that the entire function should return a `Flux<Category>` a `map` does not want a `Mono` return type, it wants a `concrete type`. So if so try changing from `map` to `flatMap`